# How to set loading is true when using useDebounce in rooks?

Tags: reactjs, debouncing

I'm using the useDebounce from rooks.

```
  const debouncedSearchFilterChange = useDebounce(setSearchFilter, 1000);

  const handleFilterChange = (filterText: string) => {
    debouncedSearchFilterChange(filterText);
  };
```

I'm trying to use a useState to set the loading:

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(
    false
  );

  const handleFilterChange = (filterText: string) => {
    setIsLoading(true); // trying to set loading to true
    debouncedSearchFilterChange(filterText);
    setIsLoading(false); // trying to set loading to false
  };
```

But my isLoading doesn't change.

When I invoke my handleFilterChange, if I console.log isLoading, then I should see:

```
console.log(isLoading)
true
// then wait 1 second
false
```

but this isn't the case.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"?

Comment: as in the isLoading doesn't change. I'll update my question.